# Positioning image with border right create create blank space

Tags: html, css, responsive

This is after position:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/bcad70bb61c5f1b6a99f0a0cd9a5405a9dd52c1e.png

I want some of the border will "swallow" in the screen like this but without creating overflow in the right side of the screen:
https://i.imagesup.co/images2/b6d97f6f3812bd958a3471fc27fd8cc5ec08a106.png.

the border creates this gap, but I don't hot to fix this. float, relative, margin, absolute still not help. What can I do?
Also overflow-x: hidden doesn't help.

```
<div>
<main>
            <img id="logo" src="Logo.png" alt=""/>

            <div id="purpuleLineBox">
                <div id="purpuleLine1"> <p>100% recyclable and bio-degradable</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine2"> <p>Simulates the natural ripening process, organic</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine3"> <p>The quickest way to achieve the  perfect avocado taste</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine4"> <p>Work with Mango, Banana, Peach, and another climacteric fruits</p> </div>
                <div id="purpuleLine5"> <p>The user interface on the bag shows when an avocado is fully ripen</p> </div>
            </div>
        </main>
</div>
```

```
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#divStyle1 {
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: #016087;
}

#divStyle2 {
    height: 10vh;
    background-color: #1D232F;
}

#logo {
    transform: rotate(5deg);
    border: 10px dashed black;
    position: absolute;
    right: -40px;
}
```

Comment: why right:-40px?

Comment: Why doesn't `overflow-x:hidden` work? https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/RwwxjZJ

Comment: Apply overflow hidden on the main tag